# What does this phrase mean?(not asking for translation)

Tags: grammar, particle-の

先生の事好きですか here means "do (you all) like (your/the) teacher?" 先生 means teacher and 事 means event. So does 先生の事 means "event of teacher"? Or precisely "the teaching of the teacher"? Then it would mean the "lesson" is the one to be liked then, not the teacher.

Comment: I THINK 事 in this instance is just referring to a 'thing'(which it can also be used to refer to)